# VSCode cannot find package in new GO installation

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have just installed Go and Visual Studio Code with tools on a new computer.
When accessing my existing projects, I get import problems, e.g.:

```
could not import golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap (cannot find package \"golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap\" in any of  
C:\Program Files\Go\src\golang.org\x\text\encoding\charmap (from $GOROOT)
C:\Users\allan\go\src\golang.org\x\text\encoding\charmap (from $GOPATH))
```

---

```
GOPATH=C:\Users\allan\go  
OS version: Windows 10.0.19043 Build 19043  
GO version: go1.17.1 windows/amd64  
Visual Studio Code version: 1.60.2 (user setup)
```

The package has actually been installed with `go get ..`
And it has been installed in:

```
c:\Users\allan\go\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\text@v0.3.7\encoding\charmap\charmap.go
```

Two things that I notice:

1. The compiler looks for `C:\Users\allan\go\src\golang.org\...` rather than `..\pkg\mod\golang.org\...`
2. The package installed has the name `text@v0.3.7` rather than just `text`.
   However, the **go.sum** file includes:

```
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.7 h1:olpwvP2KacW1ZWvsR7uQhoyTYvKAupfQrRGBFM352Gk=  
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.7/go.mod h1:u+2+/6zg+i71rQMx5EYifcz6MCKuco9NR6JIITiCfzQ=
```

So, I guess the compiler should figure out the version to use.

---

Project folder `go.mod`:

```
module github.com/Orionsg/util

go 1.16

require golang.org/x/text v0.3.7
```

And go.sum:

```
golang.org/x/text v0.3.7 h1:olpwvP2KacW1ZWvsR7uQhoyTYvKAupfQrRGBFM352Gk=
golang.org/x/text v0.3.7/go.mod h1:u+2+/6zg+i71rQMx5EYifcz6MCKuco9NR6JIITiCfzQ=
golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20180917221912-90fa682c2a6e/go.mod h1:n7NCudcB/nEzxVGmLbDWY5pfWTLqBcC2KZ6jyYvM4mQ=
```

---

Is Visual Studio Code or some other Go tool out of sync with the Go installation?

Is there something I can do to make the Go compiler use the correct directory location of packages?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you set GOROOT ?

Comment: Nope, did not know that it was required when using modules. I thought that it would use the GOPATH. It it was needed would it not be set when installing GO?
Just checked my old computer and it has no GOROOT environment variable but only GOPATH and that works fine.

Comment: No you do not need GOROOT. Is your project located under C:\Users\allan\go by any chance? And do you have a go.mod file at the root of your project?

Comment: No, my project is located in another folder, not under ...\allan\go.
The project folder does have both a go.mod and a go.sum file.
I have included their contents in the original post above.

Comment: What happens if you run `cd <your project>` followed by `go build` in `cmd` (outside VSCode)?

Comment: It seems that it is VSCode that has the problem. 
It works when just using an independent CMD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found out what was wrong. It is a VSCode issue:

When opening folders in VSCode, it no longer supports opening a top level folder with project folders below it that one can expand and close as one acesseses different projects. This worked fine earlier.

Now, one has to open each project individually as a top level folder, or the check on imports does not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If the Go project is in a sub folder of main project, then add the Go project folder to workspace(Files->Add folder to workspace) to fix this. More info [here](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/275).